# UIAlertView in viewWillDisappear crashing app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView that I pop up in my ViewController's `viewWillDisappear:` method.

What happens on iOS7 is that when I click the Cancel/OK button (that's the only button I have on my alert view as it's just an info message) my app crashes because it sends a message to a deallocated instance of my View Controller. This doesn't happen on earlier versions of iOS, so I'm very puzzled as to what is the issue and how I can fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting the delegate to the view controller if so set to nil if you do not want to do anything with it

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: darren's got it!!! that was so easy, sometimes it's frustrating how obvious things like this you can't see until someone points them out. I feel stupid :) thanks Darren

Comment: Not a problem sometimes the easy ones get you

Comment: always! you should post your answer below if you like, I can accept so that we close off the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sake of completeness and if anyone else has the same issue, I fixed this by using @darren102 suggestion. Previously I was setting the view controller as a delegate for the UIAlertView, changed this to `nil` fixed the problem.